# Java: Pressing ENTER key with Robot Class doesn't work

Tags: java, windows

```
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

It doesn't work for some reason. When I click ENTER manually, it does work. How to fix this?

Are there certain dialogs when it's required to press it manually? Because a few dialogs before this issue occurs, clicking ENTER with the robot works fine. So, seems to be a special dialog?!

Are there "special dialogs"?
If, how to automatically ENTER click then on these?

---

On Windows 7 and 10.

**EDIT:**

The whole code down below.

```
Robot r = new Robot();

            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F10);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F10);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);

            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);

            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            // ABOVE ENTER WORKS FINE! THEN A NEW WINDOW IS OPENED

            // HERE IT STOPS WORKING!
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
```

Where I put the command it stops working.

Right before that command, there's a new window opened. Now, maybe the next ENTERs aren't recognized anymore 'cause there's no focus?

But, I don't think so. Because when I click ENTER manually (without clicking anything else or moving the mouse), it does work. So apparently the focus is there.

Comment: That code looks fine, assuming `r` is an instance of `Robot`. You're going to have to add some context. Does the enter key never work via Robot? When *exactly* is the enter key not working? Are you sure you're focusing the component that takes the keypress? Does the keyTyped event work? How is your keylistener written?

Comment: @MarsAtomic I've updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Java Tutorial: "For a key press to affect a component, the [component must have the keyboard focus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html)".

Set the focus on the component you wish to detect keyPress events like this:

```
component.requestFocusInWindow();
```

In your case, you may want to detect the window opening event and then set focus.

Comment: Don't I already have the focus? I mean, when I click it manually, it works? Or is there a distinction between "physic keyboard focus" and "Java program keyboard focus"?

Comment: I don't think it's about the focus. Even when I let the program always sleep a bit and meanwhile manually click on the window - so it's definitely on focus -, it doesn't work...

Comment: I think it's about the window itself. It's about signing a Windows Speech Recognition command. Like the security stuff. Maybe this window is kind of "protected" from "not physical" keyboards? Because I've tried the exact same with a txt-file instead, which is also opened and then the next ENTERs are recognized! There's always a new line then. ----- So could it be that these windows for the signing process are "special"?

Comment: @LukasNießen Ah, sorry... I was under the impression that it was *your* window as opposed to  third party. This is potentially difficult because you have to rely on JNI to have a safe solution, but if you're sure the login window is in front, you can use robot functions like mouseMove to position the cursor where you know the target component will be and mousePress() to focus the component. At that point, your keyPress should work. keyPress tab to navigate the third party window components and keyPress alt+tab to switch between your program and third party programs. It's fragile, but try it.